# Clicking keyboard only in chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, keyboard-events

Hi I have a problem with clicking on keyboard only while being in chromedriver.

```
window = webdriver.Chrome("D:\chromedriver.exe")
window.maximize_window()
while int(mapx.get_attribute('innerText')) > 1:
      keyboard.press('a')
```

I can get html element which is responisble for this but for me it is better option to click on the keyboard. So is there any option to do this with Python+Selenium?

Comment: can you please provide the full script?

Comment: What do you mean by only in chromeDriver ?

Comment: I mean it will click wherever I'm on desktop on notepad etc and I need in to work only in chromedriver.